# date types confusion jsf

Tags: date, jsf

I stumbled upon a strange case and wanted to clarify my confusion.
so here's the issue, I am working with JPA with Hibernate ORM, and I had some dates I needed to convert from database to a more beautiful display
Exemple (2015-01-01 to January 2015).
I wrote this method :

```
public String convertDisplayDate(Date date) {
    int month = date.getMonth();
    String convertedDate = "";
    switch (month) {
    case 1:
        convertedDate += "January ";
        break;
    case 2:
        convertedDate += "February ";
        break;
    case 3:
        convertedDate += "March ";
        break;
    case 4:
        convertedDate += "April ";
        break;
    case 5:
        convertedDate += "May ";
        break;
    case 6:
        convertedDate += "June ";
        break;
    case 7:
        convertedDate += "July ";
        break;
    case 8:
        convertedDate += "August ";
        break;
    case 9:
        convertedDate += "September ";
        break;
    case 10:
        convertedDate += "October ";
        break;
    case 11:
        convertedDate += "November ";
        break;
    case 12:
        convertedDate += "December ";
        break;
    }
    convertedDate += String.valueOf(date).substring(0,4);
    return convertedDate;
}
```

it was working the first time I called it in JSF form :

```
#{candidateController.convertDisplayDate(candidateController.candidateDetail.preference.availableFrom)}
```

but then, the problem happened when I called again but with `ui:repeat` loop variable like :

```
#{candidateController.convertDisplayDate(e.fromTime)}
```

with e my loop variable.
I got an exception telling me :
noMethodFound :candidateController.convertDisplayDate(java.sql.Date) while my signature one is a java.util.Date, and I checked that all my entities are using same class Date from java.util.
so I had to write a new method for these cases :

```
public String convertDisplaySQLDate(java.sql.Date date) {
    int month = date.getMonth();
    String convertedDate = "";
    switch (month) {
    case 1:
        convertedDate += "January ";
        break;
    case 2:
        convertedDate += "February ";
        break;
    case 3:
        convertedDate += "March ";
        break;
    case 4:
        convertedDate += "April ";
        break;
    case 5:
        convertedDate += "May ";
        break;
    case 6:
        convertedDate += "June ";
        break;
    case 7:
        convertedDate += "July ";
        break;
    case 8:
        convertedDate += "August ";
        break;
    case 9:
        convertedDate += "September ";
        break;
    case 10:
        convertedDate += "October ";
        break;
    case 11:
        convertedDate += "November ";
        break;
    case 12:
        convertedDate += "December ";
        break;
    }
    convertedDate += String.valueOf(date).substring(0,4);
    return convertedDate;
}
```

and it's works, but I needed to know why I got this exception, is it because  `ui:repeat` dates get somehow converted to java.sql.Date?
can you please give me an explanation and thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not caused by JSF. This is caused by EL (the framework responsible for parsing and evaluating those `#{}` things). In older EL implementations, the method signatures have to match the argument types exactly. It doesn't check for superclasses. Your best try would be upgrading or replacing the EL implementation being used.

Nonetheless, this whole approach is unnecessary. Throw away that maintenance-unfriendly garbage and just make use of the builtin date converter:

```
<h:outputText value="#{bean.date}">
    <f:convertDateTime pattern="MMMM yyyy" locale="en_US" />
</h:outputText>
```

That's all.

It's using `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` under the covers. You can find patterns in the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).